# Автоматическое завершение программ Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8

Подскажите, пожалуйста, запущена программа IPTV, плюс включен таймер авто выключения в заданное время и вот когда настает время выключения, то пк не выключается, а пишет что ожидает завершения программы.
У Windows 7 это решалось с помощью

> Чтобы заставить операционную систему при выходе автоматически завершать работу процессов, которые не завершили свою работу в течение определенного времени (по умолчанию 20 секунд), необходимо присвоить параметру строкового типа AutoEndTasks значение 1. Он расположен в ветви реестра HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop.

Но в Windows 8.1 этого в реестре нету.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел по данной ссылке
[AutoEndTask](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/37417-autoendtask-apps-not-responding-shutdown-windows.html)